# Necesito devolver valores array de PHP de varios checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, array, foreach

estoy buscando y no consigo la forma para que mi $_POST me devuelva bien los valores checked, en una base de datos mysql tengo 10 preguntas con 6 o menos respuestas que hay que acertar para un examen, el envio del checkbox lo hago con 1[] 2[] 3[], etc. en el name="" pero en el loop que recibo por cada pregunta pude traer los campos por mysqli_fetch_assoc pero los campos checked no me los muestra en la pregunta correcta, quedan todos en la primera o la segunda, o a veces en las dos. Así esta el form:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM preguntas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
            while($campo = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) { ?>


                <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $campo['id_pregunta']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="pregunta[]" value="<?php echo $campo['pregunta']; ?>">


                <h3 class="card-title"><?php echo $campo['id_pregunta']; ?> - <?php echo $campo['pregunta']; ?></h3>

                <?php if($campo['1'] !== ''){?><input type="checkbox" name="1" value="<?php echo $campo['1']; ?>"> <?php echo $campo['1']; ?><br><?php } ?>
                <?php if($campo['2'] !== ''){?><input type="checkbox" name="2" value="<?php echo $campo['2']; ?>"> <?php echo $campo['2']; ?><br><?php } ?>
                <?php if($campo['3'] !== ''){?><input type="checkbox" name="3" value="<?php echo $campo['3']; ?>"> <?php echo $campo['3']; ?><br><?php } ?>
                <?php if($campo['4'] !== ''){?><input type="checkbox" name="4" value="<?php echo $campo['4']; ?>"> <?php echo $campo['4']; ?><br><?php } ?>
                <?php if($campo['5'] !== ''){?><input type="checkbox" name="5" value="<?php echo $campo['5']; ?>"> <?php echo $campo['5']; ?><br><?php } ?>
                <?php if($campo['6'] !== ''){?><input type="checkbox" name="6" value="<?php echo $campo['6']; ?>"> <?php echo $campo['6']; ?><br><?php } ?>
```

Y lo que recibo lo hago con foreach así:

```
foreach($_POST['id'] as $index => $nf) {


                $uno = $_POST['1'][$index];
                $dos = $_POST['2'][$index];

                $preguntas = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE id_pregunta = '$nf'");
                    while($campo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($preguntas)) {


                    // echo $uno;

                        echo '<h3>'.$campo['id_pregunta'].' - '.$campo['pregunta'].'</h3>';

                        ?>

                        <?php if($campo['1'] !== ''){ ?><input type="checkbox" <?php if(!empty($uno)){ echo 'checked disabled';} ?>> <?php echo $campo['1'];} ?><br>
                        <?php if($campo['2'] !== ''){ ?><input type="checkbox" <?php if(!empty($dos)){ echo 'checked disabled';} ?>> <?php echo $campo['2'];} ?><br>
                        <?php if($campo['3'] !== ''){ ?><input type="checkbox"> <?php echo $campo['3'];} ?><br>
                        <?php if($campo['4'] !== ''){ ?><input type="checkbox"> <?php echo $campo['4'];} ?><br>
                        <?php if($campo['5'] !== ''){ ?><input type="checkbox"> <?php echo $campo['5'];} ?><br>
                        <?php if($campo['6'] !== ''){ ?><input type="checkbox"> <?php echo $campo['6'];} ?><br>

<?php
                        }
?>
```

[image: imagen del formulario]

[image: como recibo mal el formulario donde no coinciden los checkbox marcados]

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero: Es mala idea que el nombre de un input sea numérico, aunque a la fecha no hay problemas técnicos con eso, sí te puede resultar confuso al momento de programar.

Segundo: Los checkboxes se envían por POST solo si están marcados, entonces si tratas de obtener uno no marcado `$uno = $_POST['1'];` vas a obtener un error de índice no definido.

Tercero: Estás creando los input de id como array y los checkboxes no, por lo que también deberías obtener un error de índice no definido con esto: `$uno = $_POST['1'][$index];` independientemente de que se haya marcado o no el checkbox.

Soluciones:

1.- Crea los checkboxes con nombre más específico y como array, agregando corchetes

```
            <?php if($campo['1'] !== ''){?><input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value="<?php echo $campo['1']; ?>"> <?php echo $campo['1']; ?><br><?php } ?>
            <?php if($campo['2'] !== ''){?><input type="checkbox" name="chk2[]" value="<?php echo $campo['2']; ?>"> <?php echo $campo['2']; ?><br><?php } ?>
            <?php if($campo['3'] !== ''){?><input type="checkbox" name="chk3[]" value="<?php echo $campo['3']; ?>"> <?php echo $campo['3']; ?><br><?php } ?>
            <?php if($campo['4'] !== ''){?><input type="checkbox" name="chk4[]" value="<?php echo $campo['4']; ?>"> <?php echo $campo['4']; ?><br><?php } ?>
            <?php if($campo['5'] !== ''){?><input type="checkbox" name="chk5[]" value="<?php echo $campo['5']; ?>"> <?php echo $campo['5']; ?><br><?php } ?>
            <?php if($campo['6'] !== ''){?><input type="checkbox" name="chk6[]" value="<?php echo $campo['6']; ?>"> <?php echo $campo['6']; ?><br><?php } ?>
```

2.- Asegúrate de que fueron marcados o asigna un valor por default a la variable, puedes usar if convencional o asignación ternaria (prefiero esta última)

```
foreach($_POST['id'] as $index => $nf) {
            // (si se cumple condición) ? 'Asigna esto' : 'Si no, entonces esto';
            $chk1 = (isset($_POST['chk1'][$index])) ? $_POST['chk1'][$index] : '';
            $chk2 = (isset($_POST['chk2'][$index])) ? $_POST['chk2'][$index] : '';
            $chk3 = (isset($_POST['chk3'][$index])) ? $_POST['chk3'][$index] : '';
            // El resto de tu código
}
```

Con eso ya no deberías tener problema para obtener todos tus checkboxes.

Comment: Gracias, voy a probarlo en un rato para ver si responden bien los checkbox seleccionados, los campos se llaman 1,2, 3, 4, 5 y 6 porque a veces hay hasta 6 respuestas por cada pregunta, probé cambiar los nombres por uno en 1, dos en 2 y así con los otros pero no cambiaba nada, lo mismo voy a revisar las otras cosas que me marcaste, gracias!

Comment: Me está devolviendo la web en blanco, es decir con error, cuando quito las condiciones vuelve bien, hay un problema en esta parte:

Comment: // (si se cumple condición) ? 'Asigna esto' : 'Si no, entonces esto';
             $chk1 = (isset($_POST['chk1'][$index]) ? $_POST['chk1'][$index] : '';
             $chk2 = (isset($_POST['chk2'][$index]) ? $_POST['chk2'][$index] : '';
             $chk3 = (isset($_POST['chk3'][$index]) ? $_POST['chk3'][$index] : '';
       $chk4 = (isset($_POST['chk4'][$index]) ? $_POST['chk4'][$index] : '';
       $chk5 = (isset($_POST['chk5'][$index]) ? $_POST['chk5'][$index] : '';
       $chk6 = (isset($_POST['chk6'][$index]) ? $_POST['chk6'][$index] : '';
             // El resto de tu código

Comment: No, la verdad sigue funcionando igual, me trae mal los checked, si selecciono 2º en la pregunta 1 y el 1º y 2º por ejemplo en la pregunta 2 como devolución me trae marcados 1º y 2º en la pregunta 1 y la respuesta 2 sin marcar ninguno, es como si no entendiera que tiene que marcar de cada uno y me estuviera mezclando los checkboxes en las preguntas, dejo imágenes arriba de como se ve

Comment: Ah, otro detalle no está cerrado el paréntesis del isset en tu código

Comment: Corregí los paréntesis, ahora, sería bueno que edites tu pregunta colocando el código actual para ver lo que está pasando y, por favor, incluye el resultado de `var_dump($_POST);` para ver lo que estás recibiendo y saber cómo manejarlo.